# Jquery: xml parsing of a file

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

Can anybody help me to know what's the meaning of the term 'car' in the following code? Is't the name of the file or a tag in the xml doc?

```
 $('car',xmlDoc).each(function(i) {
                    var pointData = new Array();
                ...
```

Comment: It's in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that instance, it's the name of a tag in the xml docuoment `xmlDoc`. The file file will likely look something like this:

```
<stuff>
  <car make="ford" color="blue"></car>
  <car make="chevrolet" color="red"></car>
  <car make="dodge" color="black"></car>
</stuff>
```

In this case, if you did

```
$("car", xmlDoc).each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("color");
});
```

you'd run the function 3 times, once for each `car` element and get each element's `color` attribute.